# How to find the branch for a commitId in git?

Tags: git

lets say I have a commit Id "0678dd19c498ede50e7714505eb5af3a5494beef"
I tried "git log" command, which prints,

```
$git log --full-history   1c57338cd62ee1a83df57d2c37ce1f3fa17bee17
commit 1c57338cd62ee1a83df57d2c37ce1f3fa17bee17
Author: blah@blah.com
Date:   Thu Feb 3 15:39:33 2011 -0800

Updated ejo syntax

commit 8fb7a6b3e44a020e4e495fd1c9a9976c8675c339
Author: blah@blah.com
Date:   Thu Feb 3 14:49:19 2011 -0800

Added a sample controller

commit 628788eb81c365a88ab435ffa62978077065f72c
Author: blah@blah.com
Date:   Wed Feb 2 11:33:41 2011 -0800

Test checkin
```

Is there anyway to print the branch on which this commit is made?

Comment: Do `git log` on each of the branches? A commit does not carry branch information.

Comment: I need to figure out which branches have new commits after a certain time. One way to do this would be to checkout each branch and walk the tree. But this would be inefficient. Is there a way git can tell what are the branches that had commits after a certain time?

Comment: @Nambi something along the lines of `git log --all --pretty=oneline --since=yesterday` should work (things like "1 month ago" or "2012-11-01" should work as well - see the manual page for `git log` for more information). You can change `--pretty=oneline` to a custom format that lists just the commit id and feed that to `git branch --contains` as suggested by Dylan below to get the branch names.

Comment: @twalberg `git log --all --pretty=oneline --since=yesterday` is very close to what I want. But it prints the commit hashes only not the branches. Is there a way to print the 'branch' information also?

Comment: Maybe adding `--decorate` will give the additional information you want - it will list branch names on those commits that are branch heads. Otherwise, `git log --all --pretty=format:"%H" --since="yesterday" | xargs -n1 git branch --all --contains` will work, but it's going to be quite slow.

Comment: @twalberg `git fetch` shows exactly what changed before a `fetch` command. Before fetch if i do a `git show-ref` it provides all information about branches and the commit hashes the branches are pointing to. So, using these two it is possible to calculate every other change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command you want is

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

Note that the commit may be contained in multiple branches.

Comment: I'm accepting this as answer, because this is the closest we can get. git doesn't associate a commit with a branch name. `git log` command simply displays the details of the commit. We can get the branch information as shown by @twalberg  using two commands.  Though branch calculation can be added into the logic of `git log` command itself. gitk does this calculation and displays the branches the commit belongs to.

Comment: Works, but keep in mind that you have to add an `--all` option if you want to see matches for lokal *and* remote branches.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a bit in the `git log` manual page, I came up with this, that I think will work:

```
git log --all --pretty=oneline --source --since=yesterday
```

That will list all commits on any branch added since yesterday, along with the name of the branch on which the commit lives. You might get some oddities in the presence of merges and/or new branches, and you may want to pass the output to something like `awk '{print $2}' | sort -u` to get rid of duplicates.